# Caliburn.Micro Datagrid Binding not working

Tags: wpf, binding, datagrid, caliburn.micro

I'm using Caliburn Micro in a WPF and I'm binding a BindableCollection to a datagrid. The bindable collection is a nested property. 
When populating the data from database, the binding works as expected.
But when I edit the values in the datagrid manually, the changes were not reflected in the model. (Model is not updated when values got changed in datagrid.).

```
public class Person
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public BindableCollection<Subject> Subjects;
}

public class Subject
{
    public string Title{ get; set; }
}

<UserControl x:Class="CalCompose.ViewModels.PersonView" ...ommited... >
    <Grid Margin="0">
        <TextBox x:Name="Person_Id" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="10,52,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120"/>
        <TextBox x:Name="Person_Name" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="10,90,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120"/>
        <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Person.Subjects, Mode=TwoWay}" Margin="10,177,0,0"></DataGrid>     
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Am I missing anything here?
I guess PropertyChanged notification is not sent back to Person.Subjects.
Can anyone suggest me a simple solution to overcome this issue? Thanks in advance.